# What to put to default first argument and not second in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have a function

```
def function(name="Default", age=16):
    print("My name is", name, "and I am", age)
```

How do I call the function to default the first parameter, but not the second? In the above function, I would like to have name be its default value (`"Default"`), but input the age as `200`.

I have already tried `function(,200)`; however, it says `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, pointing at the `,` in the method call.

Comment: Try `function(age=200)`

Comment: Yep. That's it. Thank you! I tried NULL and None and just couldn't think of what it might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to call the above function without the `name` parameter, is to specify the parameter you would like to change the default value of, as is done below.

```
function(age=200)
```